# How to connect Detail Class Based View to Template URL Mapping?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

How to connect Detail Class Based View to Template URL Mapping?

Here is views.py file in myapp:

```
    class ModelDetailView(DetailView):
          model = models.mymodel
          template_name = 'mymodel_detail.html'
```

Here is urls.py of myapp

```
    .....path('<pk>', ModelDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail')...........
```

Here is mymodel_detail.html file:

```
    ........<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:detail' {{object.id}} %}">{{ object.title }}</a></li>.......
```

I want that when I click on object.title, it leads me to its detailed view? How do I do that?

**Have also tried: (urls.py)**

```
      path('(?P<pk>[-\W]+)/', ModelDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail')
```

and

```
      path('detail<pk>', ModelDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path('detail/<int:pk>/', ModelDetailView.as_view(), name ='detail'),
```

Comment: What about templates url mapping `<li><a href="deatil/{{object.id}}">{{ object.title }}</a></li>`

Comment: Also tried `<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:detail' {{object.id}} %}">{{ object.title }}</a></li>`

Comment: It should be .. `href="{% url 'detail' object.id%}">`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.